# html, displaying a link as normal text

Tags: html

I was wondering if you could display a link as normal text.

```
<a id="" href="" target="_parent"><img src="" width="121" height="20" alt="">
<div style="position:absolute;left:163px;top:1px;font-size: 12px; display: block">
<font color="white">Log in</font></a>
```

I'm trying to overlap an image that is also a button, with the text "Log in", it works as it is with the code above, but I was wondering if I can change the "log in" which displays as blue and underlined to appear as normal text.

Comment: You're using `<font>`, which was deprecated a long time ago, and you're missing a `</div>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a look at Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) you can change the colour and the text style of the link.

In your example, you could use

```
<a id="" href="" target="_parent" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;"><img src="" width="121" height="20" alt="">
    <div style="position:absolute; sleft:163px;top:1px;font-size: 12px; display: block">
        <font color="white">Log in</font>
    </div>
</a>
```

However I would learn how to use external stylesheets and link them to your HTML through the `<link>` tag in the `<head>` of your html. You can then style up individual tags through the tag name, an id or a css class. So an updated example would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="link-to-your-css-file" />
```

in your css file have

```
a.imgLink{
    color: white; text-decoration: none;
}
div.imgLink{ 
    position: absolute; left: 163px; top: 1px; font-size: 12px; display: block;
}
```

Then your html would be

```
<a class="imgLink" id="" href="" target="_parent">
    <img src="" width="121" height="20" alt="">
    <div class="imgLink">
         Log In
    </div>
</a>
```

Not only does it make your HTML "dry" but it gives you greater control over the styles of your html by only changing the css file.

Answer (score 51):

In css:

```
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

These values can also be stuck in your anchor tag's `style` attribute.

Should result in your anchor tags looking the same as the text color and decoration of the parent(s).

Comment: awesome, also to disable the pointer hover effect ---

pointer-events: none;

Comment: @chantey tested pointer-events, makes it unclickable.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the link to be underlined,
set " text-decoration:none"

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer:
Yes, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burhans/EZCZZ/1/), but you probably don't want to hide links from your user.

stslavik makes a good point with "text-decoration: inherit".  Here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burhans/EZCZZ/3/).  On my browser the "blam" and "stslavic" both show with strike-through, but I'd go with the "inherit" versus the "none"; just seems better to me.

Answer (score 2):

use this code in your html file

```
<style>
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000; /* or whatever colour your text is */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

(P.S not advertising this and no spam. Click on 'Hate AI' to reach my project)
You can do this =>

```html
<h1><a style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;" href="https://obnoxiousnerd.github.io/hate-ai">Hate AI</a></h1>
        <p>A personal assistant that hates you but still helps you.</p>
```

The logic here was adding a style to the a tag which contains the following:-

```css
text-decoration: none; 
color: inherit;
```

`text-decoration` for removing the underline under the text.
`color: inherit` for removing the usual purple color of links.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - just adjust the CSS for 'a' elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple snippit to show some size/coloring possibilities, to make your link fit thematically when the rest of your text a bit better.

```html
<a href="https://www.website.com/">Wow, Look at this website! It's called Website! It's a shame that this link looks horrible, though!</a>

<h2><a style="color: #A52A2A;; text-decoration: none;" href="https://www.website.com/">Oh, boy! You can now click here to visit Website's website without the link looking bad!</a></h2>

<h2><a style="color: #A52A2A;; text-decoration: none;" href="https://www.bing.com/">Uh oh, the Website website is broken! Visit the pinnacle of innovation, Bing, instead!</a></h2>
```