# Remove default hyperlink color and text decoration in HTML mail format C#

Tags: c#, html-email

I want to remove the default formatting(the blue text and underline) for shared UNC paths(`\\<servername\folder>`) in my html mail format.
By default, they are links when we use html mail format. Here's is my sample code doing that.

```
 private string GetReportContent()
    {
        string report = "";

        string htmlTableStart = @"<table>";
        string htmlTableEnd = "</table>";
        string htmlHeaderRowStart = @"<tr style=""text-align:center;"">";
        string htmlHeaderRowEnd = "</tr>";
        string htmlTrStart = "<tr>";
        string htmlTrEnd = "</tr>";
        string htmlTdStart = @"<td style=""border-style:solid; border-width:thin;"">";
        string htmlTdEnd = "</td>";
        string ErrorStyle = @"style=""background-color: #f44b42;color:white;text-decoration: none;""";

        report += "<h3>Table 1</h3></br>";

        report += htmlTableStart;
        report += htmlHeaderRowStart;
        report += htmlTdStart + "Location" + htmlTdEnd;
        report += htmlTdStart + "Last Update Time" + htmlTdEnd;
        report += htmlTdStart + "PTF Size" + htmlTdEnd;
        report += htmlHeaderRowEnd;

        string pth = @"\\Server1\Docs\model\part_table.ptf";
        DateTime dt = File.GetLastWriteTime(pth);
        long len = new System.IO.FileInfo(pth).Length;

        dt = DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0);

        if ((DateTime.Now - dt).Days > 1)
            report += @"<tr " + ErrorStyle + ">";
        else
            report += htmlTrStart;
        report += htmlTdStart + pth + htmlTdEnd;
        report += htmlTdStart + dt.ToString() + htmlTdEnd;
        report += htmlTdStart + GetStrFileSize(len) + htmlTdEnd;
        report += htmlTrEnd;
```

This sends out the UNC path as link and my text becomes blue though I set it as white in my inline style for that `</tr>` . I tried using `text-decoration:none` as well but no luck.

Comment: what about [using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636105/html-displaying-a-link-as-normal-text)?

Comment: Removing it will not work. Outlook & Gmail creates link by itself. Use inline CSS on the `<a>` tag and you should be fine.

Comment: The prob is we dont have contril on anchor link generation. C# will make them links by default.. Without my control..pls cgeck my code above